# R - Finding centroids of different id values

Tags: r

I'm trying to find the centroids for a SpatialPointsDataFrame I created. The following is a snippet of the data frame called "spdf".

```
    Name    X   Y
1   16  56  39
2   16  57  39
3   16  55  38
4   16  55  37
5   16  54  38
6   16  55  39
7   16  55  40
8   12  58  41
9   12  56  45
10  12  58  43
11  12  56  42
12  12  55  44
13  12  55  47
```

I'm using the function "gCentroid" from the "rgeos" package to identify centroids. I'm able to calculate the centroid for the entire data frame with `gCentroid(spdf, byid = FALSE)` but I get errors when I try to calculate centroids based on the "Name" field using `gCentroid(spdf, byid = TRUE, id = "Name")`. In other words, based on the above data, I'd like to get two centroids for the Names "12" and "16". The documentation on gCentroid is sparse regarding the "id" field. Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can calculate centroids for each "Name"?

Comment: Your question is not reproducible. You need to add `library(sp) ; coordinates(spdf) = c("X", "Y")` in there

Comment: Sorry. Yes, you are correct David. I needed to add that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation is slightly confusing, but you aren't specifying the ID input, you are specifying output. Each point in your example has it's own ID (the rownames of the data frame which must by definition be unique). You can easily get your desired output however, by subsetting your data frame by the unique values in `df$Name` and calculating the centroids this way...

```
ctrs <- lapply( unique( df$Name ) , function(x) gCentroid( SpatialPoints( df[ df$Name == x , c('X','Y') ] ) ) )
setNames( ctrs , unique(df$Name ) )
#$`16`
#SpatialPoints:
#         x        y
#1 55.28571 38.57143
#Coordinate Reference System (CRS) arguments: NA 

#$`12`
#SpatialPoints:
#         x        y
#1 56.33333 43.66667
#Coordinate Reference System (CRS) arguments: NA
```

p.s. I always thought you should be able to do this my having an object of `SpatialCollections` but it seems you cannot specify a `list` of Spatial objects of the same type (despite what the documentation for that class says).

Comment: One thing I notice is that there is no "Name" associated with the SpatialPoints after running the gCentroid. Is there someway to reattach that to the output or am I just missing something?

Comment: @user2359494 sure. I've updated slightly to show how you might do that with a call to `setNames`. HTH.

Answer (score 1):

If you're computing centroids by taking the average of the X and Y values, you can use `aggregate`:

```
aggregate(.~Name, data=dat, mean)
#   Name        X        Y
# 1   12 56.33333 43.66667
# 2   16 55.28571 38.57143
```

This appears to match the results from `gCentroid`:

```
library(sp)
library(rgeos)
spdf <- dat
coordinates(spdf) <- c("X", "Y")
gCentroid(spdf[spdf$Name == 12,], byid=FALSE)
# SpatialPoints:
#          x        y
# 1 56.33333 43.66667
# Coordinate Reference System (CRS) arguments: NA 
gCentroid(spdf[spdf$Name == 16,], byid=FALSE)
# SpatialPoints:
#          x        y
# 1 55.28571 38.57143
# Coordinate Reference System (CRS) arguments: NA
```

Comment: However, be careful, this may not be the case when you are taking the centroids of points that are projected (i.e. have a valid `proj4string`), especially over large geographic distances... (points on  a sphere)

Comment: Thanks Josilber. You are correct that this appears to work too. I'm going back and forth on whether to use this method (which is clean) or that of Simon's above. I guess I prefer to use the function inherent to gCentroid in case I use a projection in the future.

Comment: @SimonO'Hanlon thanks -- that is certainly true and with projected points your approach is definitely the better one to take!